# Angular 2 Inline template cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, templates

I am trying to render data inside a tab body section based on clicking an icon on a tabset. Here is a screen shot of my initial, successfully rendered view:

[image]

But when I click a new tabset icon to load data into the tab body section, I get the following exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_DnDMiniCardGroupComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/PaletteSchemaModule/DnDMiniCardGroupComponent/component.ngfactory.js:144)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:425)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:620)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (view.js:410)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_TabCommunityComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/PaletteSchemaModule/TabCommunityComponent/component.ngfactory.js:89)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:425)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:620)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (view.js:410)
at View_TypesContentComponent2.detectChangesInternal (/PaletteSchemaModule/TypesContentComponent/component.ngfactory.js:190)
at View_TypesContentComponent2.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:425)
at View_TypesContentComponent2.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:620)
at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (view_container.js:67)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_TypesContentComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/PaletteSchemaModule/TypesContentComponent/component.ngfactory.js:592)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:425)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:620)
```

Here is a slice of my tabset template that shows tab content body based on `ngSwitch` and `ngSwitchCase`:

```
<div class="schema-palette" [ngSwitch]="tabId">
    <myapp-base-palette *ngSwitchCase="'T'">
        <myapp-tabset [tabType]="'T'" (onTabSelected)="tabChanged($event)" palette-tabset></myapp-tabset>
        <myapp-tab-community palette-content-region></myapp-tab-community>
    </myapp-base-palette>
</div>
```

Here is my `myapp-tab-community` component template:

```
<div class="community-buffer" ngFor="let miniCardGrp of miniCardGrps; let i = index">
  <div style="height:5px" *ngIf="i === 0"></div>
  <myapp-dnd-mini-card-group [miniCardGrp]="miniCardGrp"></myapp-dnd-mini-card-group>
</div>
```

Here is `myapp-tab-community` component typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import { PalettesService } from '../../palettes.service';
import { MiniCardGroup } from '../../palettes.helpers';
import { DnDMiniCardGroupComponent } from '../../shared/dnd-mini-card-group/dnd-mini-card-group.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'myapp-tab-community',
  templateUrl: './tab-community.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab-community.component.scss'],
  providers: [PalettesService]
})
export class TabCommunityComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  miniCardGrps: MiniCardGroup[];

  constructor(private palettesService: PalettesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.miniCardGrps = [];
    this.miniCardGrps = this.palettesService.getTemplateTypes();

    // DATA IS SUCCESSFULLY RETRIEVED
    console.log('TabCommunityComponent.ngOnInit = ' + JSON.stringify(this.miniCardGrps));
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // ERROR BLOCKS EVALUATION
    console.log('TabCommunityComponent.ngAfterViewInit = ' + JSON.stringify(this.miniCardGrps));
  }

  trackByMiniCardGroup(index: number, miniCardGrp: MiniCardGroup) {
    return miniCardGrp.category;
  }

}
```

An array of `myapp-dnd-mini-card-group` components should be rendered but the error is thrown from its template.

The template file:

```
<div class="mini-card-grp-collapse">
  <div class="mini-card-grp-collapse-row">
    <div class="mini-card-grp-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" [href]="href" aria-expanded="true" attr.aria-controls="{{ ariaControls }}">
        <!-- THIS LINE THROWS -->
        <md-icon class="white-text md-16">play_arrow</md-icon>{{ miniCardGrp.category }}
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="mini-card-grp-title-helper">
      <md-icon class="white-text md-24">help_outline</md-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse in" [id]="id">
  <div class="mini-card-wrapper" *ngFor="let miniCard of miniCardGrp.miniCards">
    <myapp-dnd-mini-card [miniCard]="miniCard"></myapp-dnd-mini-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the typescript file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { MathHelper } from '../../../../utils/math';
import { MiniCardGroup } from '../../palettes.helpers';

import { DndMiniCardComponent } from '../dnd-mini-card/dnd-mini-card.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'myapp-dnd-mini-card-group',
  templateUrl: './dnd-mini-card-group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dnd-mini-card-group.component.scss']
})
export class DnDMiniCardGroupComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit 
{

  @Input() miniCardGrp: MiniCardGroup;
  @Input() href: string;
  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() ariaControls: string;

  constructor() {
    let mathHelper = new MathHelper();
    let random$ = mathHelper.getRandomNumberString();
    this.id = random$;
    this.href = '#' + random$;
    this.ariaControls = random$;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // IS UNDEFINED
    console.log('DnDMiniCardGroupComponent.ngOnInit = ' + JSON.stringify(this.miniCardGrp));
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // IS NEVER REACHED
    console.log('DnDMiniCardGroupComponent.ngAfterViewInit = ' + JSON.stringify(this.miniCardGrp));
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

As requested, here is what the `mini-card-group` component looks like:

```
<div class="btn-grp-collapse">
  <div class="btn-grp-collapse-row">
    <div class="btn-grp-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" [href]="href" aria-expanded="true" attr.aria-controls="{{ ariaControls }}">
        <md-icon class="white-text md-16">play_arrow</md-icon>{{ dndButtonGrp.title }}
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-grp-title-helper">
      <md-icon class="white-text md-24">help_outline</md-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse in" [id]="id">
  <div class="btn-wrapper" *ngFor="let dndButton of dndButtonGrp.dndButtons">
    <myapp-dnd-button [dndButton]="dndButton"></myapp-dnd-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Its typescript file:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { MathHelper } from '../../../../utils/math'
import { DnDButtonGroup } from './dnd-button-group.helpers';

import { DndButtonComponent } from '../dnd-button/dnd-button.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'myapp-dnd-button-group',
  templateUrl: './dnd-button-group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dnd-button-group.component.scss']
})
export class DnDButtonGroupComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() dndButtonGrp: DnDButtonGroup;
  @Input() href: string;
  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() ariaControls: string;

  constructor() {
    let mathHelper = new MathHelper();
    let random$ = mathHelper.getRandomNumberString();
    this.id = random$;
    this.href = '#' + random$;
    this.ariaControls = random$;
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `{{ miniCardGrp?.category }}`?

Comment: I tried this and *ngIf="miniCardGrp" but it doesn't render even though I confirmed my service returns the data.

Comment: How did you confirm that?

Comment: Chrome console output:

DnDMiniCardGroupComponent.ngOnInit = undefined
dnd-mini-card-group.component.ts:33 DnDMiniCardGroupComponent.ngAfterViewInit = undefined

Comment: It is undefined..

Comment: I think `[miniCardGrp]="miniCardGrp"` should be `[miniCardGrp]="miniCardGrps"` It's a typo I think..

Comment: Its not as its in a ngFor block: <div class="community-buffer" ngFor="let miniCardGrp of miniCardGrps; let i = index">
  <div style="height:5px" *ngIf="i === 0"></div>
  <myapp-dnd-mini-card-group [miniCardGrp]="miniCardGrp"></myapp-dnd-mini-card-group>
</div>

Comment: @Chris could you show us MiniCardGroup class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to implement dynamic components to render content for each tab. Here is the relevant link for a full background:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html

Answer (score 0):

When you call the service the data might not be arrived yet, you need to subscribe to the service to get the data

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.palettesService
    .getTemplateTypes()
    .subscribe(data => this.miniCardGrps = data);
}
```

Comment: I think your right but I have to rewire my service. Will get back to this tonight. Will keep you updated. Thanks for your assistance Roman.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I can successfully retrieve my JSON payload in the constructor of my component and assign it to this.miniCardGrps. But it loses its value outside of the constructor and the template is not rendered, even when piping async. What did I miss here?

Comment: Your mistake is to do it in the constructor. See my updates.